# Need Help setting up Certificate Chain for a LAMP stack with nginx proxy docker

Tags: docker, nginx

I have a LAMP Stack docker set up with:

1. Nginx proxy Docker https://hub.docker.com/r/jwilder/nginx-proxy
2. Apache Stack

Everything is working fine except that when we check our SSL on ssllabs.com, we are getting report of: certificate chain missing.

If you are familiar working with this nginx proxy docker and LAMP stack, i need your advise to get this chain certficate up.

Just wonder if you can help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

when you get a certificate from a certificate authority(for example let's encrypt), they will give you some files. between those files you have a key and a cert and a bundle file. all you need to do is just to append your bundle file contents to your cert file and then you will end up with a file known as fullchain file. then replace the address of this file with the address of your cert file in your configuration and do a restart. (browsers will automatically complete the chain even if your not provided it, but tools like curl want your server to explicitly mention the chain of your cert.)